# OptaPlanner cloning corruption with gizmo

Tags: optaplanner

OptaPlanner 9.44.0 w/Java 11 on Windows 11.

I have a system with a shadow variable. When I run with normal domain access, everything works fine. But I'm trying out GIZMO domain access and I'm getting the error below (where `MyInstance` is the `toString()` of my actual class):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cloning corruption: the same entity (MyInstance) is present in both the original and the clone.
So when a planning variable in the original solution changes, the cloned solution will change too.
```

I tried running with various assert levels and there are no issues detected unless I use GIZMO. I tried adding `@DeepPlanningClone` on every related class and field but it made no difference.

Some other possibly relevant details:

- The class it's complaining about has a `@ShadowVariable` on it (which is a `List`).
- In the solution class, the class it's complaining about is held in a collection (`List`, marked as `@PlanningEntityCollectionProperty`)
- The class it's complaining about is actually a subclass of an abstract base class. The subclass does not add any new member variables, just helper methods.
- I have a `VariableListener` for setting the shadow variable fields appropriately.

Any idea what could be going wrong here? Unfortunately I can't share my actual code :(

Comment: IIRC we fixed a bug with Gizmo/Quarkus on Timefold Solver (the open source fork of OptaPlanner) some time ago. Try [a quick upgrade to Timefold Solver 1.2.0](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork#upgrade-from-optaplanner-to-timefold) (which will need at least Java 17) and confirm it's fixed there. If not, we'd love a reproducer so we can fix it.

Comment: I updated to Timefold 1.2.0 and I get the same error. I'm not even certain what it's trying to clone. When I run without gizmo it uses the same object instances throughout the entire search. Anyway, I don't actually need the performance boost this would provide (which is probably pretty small anyway) but I do wonder if this means I'm doing something wrong somewhere and it only gets exposed through gizmo.

Comment: Can you provide us a reproducer and [create a new issue](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues) for us with a link to the reproducer? Bugs get priority. If we get it fast enough, it might make 1.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide us a reproducer [new issue](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues), we'd love to fix this for 1.3.0.

**Workaround for 1.2.0**

In `src/main/resources/application.properties`, disable gizmo:

```
quarkus.timefold.solver.domain-access-type=REFLECTION
```

**Update: the fix is out in 1.3.0**

Thanks to the reproducer, this was fixed for [1.3.0](https://github.com/timefoldai/timefold-solver/releases), which is out now.

Comment: I have created an issue with a reproducer here: https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues/339

Comment: Thanks, that's fixed for 1.3.0 (credit goes to Chris and Lukas).